# Visual force Error-System.TypeException: Invalid decimal

Tags: apex, visualforce, geolocation

i  have written  code  in apex while saving the  Geo location in my detail page. While doing this an error is coming  on this particular line.It throw an error on my particular  this code

```
newSupply.GeoLocation__Latitude__s=decimal.valueOf(latitude);
newSupply.GeoLocation__Longitude__s=decimal.valueOf(longitude);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to debug your `decimal.valueOf(latitude)`?

Comment: @mast0r yes sir but  its showing null.

Comment: Well you should then check the implementation of those variables `latitude / longitude `

Comment: @mast0r  sir i have used     '  public String latitude {get; set; }
    public String longitude {get; set ;}
    public String GeoLocation{ get; set; }'

Comment: `Decimal.valueOf(null);` will throw a `System.TypeException: Invalid decimal` error.

Comment: @BarCotter  sir but what is the possible solution for this :(

Comment: You could put a null guard around that piece of code.

Comment: @BarCotter yeah .!! Got it .!! Thanx guys